# How to isolate transactions with hibernate

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, transactions

I have read the `hibernate` documentation concerning the `isolation levels` and I tried them in an example using `PostgreSql` to check if they guarantee the thread safety when transaction on the same data set are performed concurrently. I use the strongest `isolation level`, the `Serializable` as:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">8</property>
```

The piece of code is:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    IntStream.range(0, 20).forEach(t -> {
        service.submit(() -> {
            updateSalary(2L);
        });
    });

static void updateSalary(long id) {

    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx =  s.beginTransaction();
        Customer c = (Customer) s.load(Customer.class, id);
        c.setSalary(c.getSalary() + 10);

        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        s.close();
    }

}
```

However an exception is thrown:

```
 org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

If I synchronize the method `updateSalary()` using `ReentrantLock` as :

```
static void updateSalary(long id) {
    lock.lock();
    Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        tx =  s.beginTransaction();
        Customer c = (Customer) s.load(Customer.class, id);
        c.setSalary(c.getSalary() + 10);

        tx.commit();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        tx.rollback();
    }
    finally {
        s.close();
    }
    lock.unlock();
}
```

it works and it is thread safe. Is that the appropriate way to achieve thread safety in hibernate transactions? If no, what is the recommendable way? How could one achieve thread safety using `Session.buildLockRequest()` in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are not intended to make programs thread-safe.  They're used to guarantee that a group of changes to a database either is applied in full or not at all, including ensuring that the data you have read did not change during the transaction.

The behaviour that you are seeing is fully expected.  The database detected a concurrent update and threw an exception notifying you of this so you may take appropriate action (like trying again, or informing the user that data may have changed).

Comment: What happens if multiple requests come to server while trying to modify the same set of data? Is the isolation level "Serializable" adequate to ensure data consistency? Why does not it work with multiple threads?

Comment: Just because an exception was thrown warning you of a concurrent update does not mean the data became inconsistent.  In fact, the exception means that a potential inconsistent update would have occured but PostgreSQL refused it.  Your data is still consistent, or did you experience that it wasn't?

Comment: The "update" is executed only 5 times not 20, which is the number of threads.

Comment: Yes, so you would expect salary to have increased by 50 total.  The other 15 times failed to do an update, but did not corrupt the salary data by doing an incorrect calculation.  Run your code without a transaction and see what happens then... you will find that despite all updates having occured, the salary won't be 200 higher even though your program printed 20 times that it increased the salary by 10 (in other words, it is not consistent anymore).

Comment: I do not intend to run it without a transaction. I need to know, how can all transactions be executed properly to bring the database to the expected state.

Comment: You need to retry it when there was a concurrent update.  So if there is an exception of that type, restart the transaction and try it again.  Note however that the salary may have changed and your update may not be what you intended anymore.  Let's say salary is 3000 and a user wants to set the salary to 2000, and another user wants to increase the salary by 100, what would your intended end result be?  2100?  2000? 3100?  When a transaction fails due to a concurrent update, you need to be prepared to abandon it if it its initial premise (increase salary or setting salary) is no longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

As john16384 replied, Transactions are meant to make sure a group of statements are executed together or not.

I would not put locks on critical method as it will impact the performance and scalability. I would let methods to execute concurrently , but use the Hibernates VERSION column to figure out whether the data has been updated after it was fetched. You can find tons of materials on using Hibernate VERSION column approach.